# Have any professional sporting tiebreaks been decided by a coin toss (or equivalent)?

Tags: trivia, tie-breaker

In most professional sporting events that involve some form of ranking system to determine an overall winner, or progression into later stages, there are a series of tie-breaker rules to determine a winner / loser when the primary ranking metric is tied across two or more competitors.

For example, for the 2018 FIFA World Cup, the tie-breakers for the group stage were as follows:

> 1. greatest number of points obtained in all group matches;
> 2. goal difference in all group matches;
> 3. greatest number of goals scored in all group matches.
>
> [...]
>
> 1. greatest number of points obtained in the group matches between the teams concerned;
> 2. goal difference resulting from the group matches between the teams concerned;
> 3. greater number of goals scored in all group matches between the teams concerned;
> 4. greater number of points obtained in the fair play conduct of the teams based on yellow and red cards received in all group matches;
> 5. drawing of lots by the FIFA.
>
> <sub>https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/tie-breakers-for-russia-2018-groups</sub>

Quite a lot of these tie-breakers end a coin toss, or another "luck of the draw" type scenario, to determine the "winner".

My question is: has any professional sporting event ever had to use its final *"it's down to luck"* tie-breaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of examples of this, but mostly from the days when they didn't have nearly as many tiebreakers *before* the "coin toss". Some football examples:

- In [Group F of the 1990 World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F), a drawing of lots was used to decide the positions of the Republic of Ireland and the Netherlands in the group.
- [The 1968 European Championship semi-final between Italy and the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_1968#Semi-finals).
- [The 1964-5 European Cup quarter-final between Liverpool and Köln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964%E2%80%9365_European_Cup#Second_leg_3)

The latter two would these days have been settled by a penalty shootout; the former would *probably* have used one of the "disciplinary record" tie-breakers but I haven't looked into the details.